# How to merge PNGS with alpha channels into one larger image?

Tags: php, transparency, gd

I am trying to layer these:

[image: gametile_masked_file]
[image: gamertile_masked_file]
[image: sanctum-background.png]

into this:

[image]

But what I keep getting is this:

[image]

This is the relevant code, Im not sure what Im missing:

```
    $sig_background = imagecreatefrompng("sanctum-signature.png");
imagealphablending($sig_background, false);
imagesavealpha($sig_background, true);
$sig_gamertile = imagecreatefrompng($gamertile_masked_file);
imagealphablending($sig_gamertile, false);
imagesavealpha($sig_gamertile, true);
$sig_gametile = imagecreatefrompng($gametile_masked_file);
imagealphablending($sig_gamertile, false);
imagesavealpha($sig_gamertile, true);
imagecopymerge($sig_background, $sig_gamertile, 175, 2, 0, 0, 64, 64, 100);
imagecopymerge($sig_background, $sig_gametile, 342, 20, 0, 0, 64, 64, 100);
```

If any more information is missing, please let me know and Ill try to fill in the blanks. Thank you for your time.

edit - here are links to the files (hosted on photobucket)
[gamertile](http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y195/gViscardi/misc/darkcollins-masked.png)
[gametile](http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y195/gViscardi/misc/1Wdsb2JhbC9ECgUNGgMfVlonL2ljb24vMC84MDAwAAAAAAAAAPpVSyA-masked.png)

Comment: by the way the gametile and gamertile get rendered on the last screenshot, it doesn't look like your mask is applied properly in your source PNG. Can you post link to some source images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your code, is it a copy/paste error or a real bug?

You do:

```
$sig_gamertile = imagecreatefrompng($gamertile_masked_file);
imagealphablending($sig_gamertile, false);
imagesavealpha($sig_gamertile, true);
```

And then:

```
$sig_gametile = imagecreatefrompng($gametile_masked_file);
```

But straight afterwards, you continue to call functions on `$sig_gamertile` instead of `$sig_gametile`:

```
imagealphablending($sig_gamertile, false);
imagesavealpha($sig_gamertile, true);
```

Obviously radically renaming some vars would help guard against this.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
imagealphablending($im, false);
```

disables alpha blending. Use *true* instead of *false*.